# Journey data greyed out in 'Update Object' activity in Journey

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I have a cloud page with smartcapture. I am using this Cloudpage as entry criteria into a journey that creates a new record and updates an Object in SF. i am able to map all required fields to the Journey data (see below) except one field (**NPS Rate**) which is greyed out. (second screenshot)

[image]

[image]

why would this be? I have the receiving field in SF with data type 'number' and the same for the smartcapture target DE.

Comment: Do you have any number fields in your journey data?

Comment: Yes this field is a number field. Should I change it to text? If yes, Does the Salesforce field also need to be text?

Comment: I believe a salesforce number field has to map to a decimal DE field

Comment: I changed it to decimal & it works now however I am really struggling to pass a constant 0 from the Email to the Cloud page. I tried ```@nps = 0 @nps = '0' @nps = "0"```

Comment: havent tried it, but maybe 0.0 works.

Comment: my wife suggested that last night and 0.0 seems to work. It sends a 0 :)

Comment: Actually it was "00" which i tried which seemed to have worked.